# Can't call a WebMethod using javascript (html)

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, consuming

CalculadoraWebService:

```
package in.gruporia.javawebservice;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "CalculadoraWebService")
public class CalculadoraWebService {

//Retorna la SUMA de dos numeros enteros
@WebMethod(operationName = "AddIntegers")
public int add(@WebParam(name = "firstNum") int num1, @WebParam(name = "secondNum") int num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

//Retorna la RESTA de dos numeros enteros
@WebMethod(operationName = "SubIntegers")
public int sub(@WebParam(name = "firstNum") int num1, @WebParam(name = "secondNum") int num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
}

//Retorna el PRODUCTO de dos numeros enteros
@WebMethod(operationName = "MulIntegers")
public int mul(@WebParam(name = "firstNum") int num1, @WebParam(name = "secondNum") int num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
}

//Retorna la DIVISION de dos numeros enteros
@WebMethod(operationName = "DivideIntegers")
public int div(@WebParam(name = "firstNum") int num1, @WebParam(name = "secondNum") int num2) {
    return num1 / num2;
}
```

}

---

Index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>UseSwap</title>
    <script>
     var service;
     function InitializeService(){
      service.useService("http://localhost:8080/Calculadora/CalculadoraWebService?wsdl", "CalculadoraWebService");
     }
     var num1, num2, result;
     function Add(){
      num1 = document.DemoForm.Numero1.value;
      console.log(num1);
      num2 = document.DemoForm.Numero2.value;
      console.log(num2);
      result = service.CalculadoraWebService.callService("add", num1, num2);
      console.log(result);
      alert(event.result.value);
     }


     </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="InitializeService()" id="service" 
    style="behavior:url(webservice.htc)">

        <form name="DemoForm">
       Numero 1 : <input type="text" name="Numero1"/>

       Numero 2 : <input type="text" name="Numero2"/>
       <button onclick="Add()">Resultado</button>
      </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

---

The CalculadoraWebService works fine, I consumed it with java in a previews excercise, calling all the methods but now I've to do it using javascript.
num1 and num2 values are fine, but an error appears

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'callService' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a scope problem, define `service` as a var outside the function that initializes it, here is the snippet:

```
var service; //add this
function InitializeService(){
    service.useService("http://localhost:8080/Calculadora/CalculadoraWebService?wsdl", "GetSumService");
}
```

If you dont declare `service` outside the function `InitializeService`, Js will declare that variable inside the scope of that function, and then when you try to use it in your Add function, the scope of that function won't see the `service` var.

Comment: It continues giving me this error `Unable to get property 'GetSumService' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Then you must have a definition of service somewhere else, is this your full code?

Comment: I still believe there some JS code missing, I dont see where you declare `service` in your code (without my answer, of course). `service` must be being declared somewhere in your code, I need to see that code.

Comment: I did not mean that You should add my code, It seems that service is being declared previously than the JS code you've shared.